# How to change the floating label color of TextInputLayout and the cursor, without changing `colorAccent` in `AppTheme`

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext, android-color

This question is related to two other questions that I'll specifically name below. The difference being, that I specifically ask for a way to change the color without the use of the base `AppTheme`.

In the [first related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30546430/4687402), the proposed solution includes setting

`<item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>` in `AppTheme`

However, it also says to make a theme/style specifically for the `TextInputLayout`, which looks like this:

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/Color Name</item> 
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/Color Name</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Color Name</item>
</style>
```

So the `colorAccent`is set twice. I tried this and came to the conclusion that the specific theme for the `TextInputLayout` is unnecessary, as I got the same result, with and without it. Only setting the `colorAccent` in the `AppTheme` is sufficient. This works but isn't necessarily what I want/need.

In the [second related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32584788/4687402), people suggest to, again, modify the `AppTheme` and setting `colorAccent` (and other attributes).

However, I don't find this solution right/satisfying. There should be a way to specifically change that one color without changing the style of the whole app, which the person posing the second question also criticizes in one of his/her comments.

**So, what I am specifically looking for here**, is a solution, in XML or programmatically, to specifically **change the color of the floating hint/label and cursor** of the `TextInputLabel`+`TextInputEditText` Combo. Basically **the same behavior I'd get when setting `colorAccent`**.

Is there a way to do this or did the SDK developers seriously make it only possible by setting `colorAccent`?

PS I realize that this might work with making a new Theme, inheriting from `AppTheme` and setting it to the activities that I want to have the specific color. However, as I said, thats not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom style like this:

```
    <style name="myInputText">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/myColor</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size</item>
     ...
     </style>
```

Now, you can directly use this in `TextInputLayout`, no need to provide any parent in style or change your app theme.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:textColorHint="@color/myColor" 
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/myInputText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
```

**EDIT**

This only changes the color of the floating label, not the cursor. To also change the cursor color, you need to create a drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="10dp"
          android:width="2dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/myColor"/>
</shape>
```

and add it to the style you use for the `TextInputEditText`, *not* the `TextInputLayout`.

```
<style name="Settings.TextInputEditText">
    ...
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: When I try to set `android:hintTextAppearance`in a style, it can't be resolved at all. When I only set `hintTextAppearance` in style or directly in `TextInputLayout`, the text loses all color and becomes very small. Also, setting `textColorHint` only changes the color of the hint while the focus isn't on the `TextInputEditText`. As soon as it gets focus, the floating text, again, becomes the standard green color.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I somehow messed up earlier. Let me know if this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Change you want to color in res/color - and your favorite color as define 3 color you can change effect

Comment: Im sorry but I really don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: open color and change color for see effect -  http://prntscr.com/o8wx91

Comment: I see what you mean. However, in my question I specifically said that thats not the way I want it done. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set the `colorAccent` for the views you want, only... Something like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeInputLayout" />
```

Then, in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppThemeInputLayout" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

I guess this way you can change the `colorAccent` for specific views only (and not for whole app)

Let me know if that works for you.. Otherwise, I will delete this answer.

Comment: As I said in my last sentence, I realize that I can do that. However, thats a very unsatisfying workaround instead of a straight way to do this. What Im looking for is something like `<item name="floatingLabelColor">#F00</item>`